# Ubuntu 13.10 Bad Video quality/coloring (AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series)

Tags: drivers, gnome, ati, video, 13.10

I just recently installed Ubuntu 13.10 Alongside Windows XP. I had problems with the Screen resolution but I was able to resolve that problem installing a different version of the Gnome Shell.

Now the only problem I have video related that I can think of is the colour. It looks terrible, I have a AMD Radeon HD 6700 Series Graphics card and I installed AMD Catalyst control center earlier today. It didn't seem to fix any problem I had. I am new to the Ubuntu OS so I know
 very little aside from some terminal commands... I also have a screenshot though I'm not sure that will help with the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source drivers that come with Ubuntu 13.10 aren't that great, but Catalyst is not the driver for your GPU. Catalyst is only advised if you have a Radeon HD 7000 or greater. Get the latest open source drivers via oibaf's PPA. Be sure to remove Catalyst first.

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx -y; sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers; sudo sed -i 's/saucy/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oibaf*; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

Comment: Well that fixed the color problem, now I have a problem when using the resolution 1920x1080, everything goes off screen.

Comment: Try also running sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf and then reboot.

Comment: I end up getting this 
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/X11/xorg.conf’: No such file or directory

Comment: Everything should work fine then. I've got Ubuntu 13.10 running on two Radeon HD 6850 machines behind me at 1920x1080. I'm not sure what's causing your off screen issue, an overscan issue with your display?

Comment: Could just be my monitor. I am fine with 1360x768.